# Console.ReadLine() without pressing Enter

Tags: c#

When i use:

```
string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
```

The user has to drop the item and then press Enter.
I want the user of my Console Application to be able to drag and drop a file into the Console Application Window and take the name of that file without him having to press Enter every time he drops the item as he has to drop a bunch of items.

The files extensions are .xlsx and .py. Is there a way of telling ReadLine to stop reading when it encounters these substrings?

Comment: Loop using Console.Read(), break when you get the extension? Although in that case if someone named their file blah.xlsxBlah.py you might be screwed

Comment: You probably better create a UI application to handle this properly.

Comment: You could loop Console.Read and have a timer in the background which detects when no new characters come in for a couple of milliseconds. Still a little bit shaky so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop with Console.ReadKey(), extract the returned characters.

```
var filename = "";
do
{
    filename+= Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;

} while (!(filename.StartsWith("\"") && filename.EndsWith(".xlsx\"")) 
       && filename.EndsWith(".xlsx")); //continue with other extension
```

Notice the closing double quote, since you'll get quotes enclosing the filename if there's any space. This will break if there's .xlsx in the middle of the file name.

Comment: There won't be any .xlsx in the middle so this solution works perfect. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

As i know there is no really good solution for that case except making your own GUI. C# console cannot receive events from file drop, because `csrss.exe` owns that window not your app.

Next solution will not work in many cases, but if that just feature for testing not production i think that's enough.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder fileNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        ConsoleKeyInfo cki = new ConsoleKeyInfo();

        do
        {
            while (Console.KeyAvailable == false)
                Thread.Sleep(250); 
            cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            fileNameBuilder.Append(cki.KeyChar);
        } while (!fileNameBuilder.ToString().EndsWith(".xlsx") || !fileNameBuilder.ToString().EndsWith(".py"));

        var fileName = fileNameBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know to do this, is by dragging files on the .exe file of your program, then reading their names from `args[]` (passed to `main`) and load them like you would with any file in C#.

Other way is by having a GUI, in that case you can add `DragEventHandler` objects to handle drag & drop events. (and data, too).